# What is highstock.js - modules- canvas-tools?

Tags: canvas, highcharts

Just downloaded highstock 1.1.6.  The js directory includes a modules folder, which has a file named `canvas-tools.js`.  I have looked around both [highstocks.com](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) and [highslide.com](http://www.highslide.com/) as well as searched their forums, but for the life of me I cannot find any documentation about what the module is or how to use it with highstock.js

Might anyone on here be able to shed some light on this most mysterious of javascript libraries?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's for SVG compatibility on Android. See http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility

Comment: To be exact: it's for the stock browser on android <= 2.3 and some other older browsers/platforms. The stock browser on android 3+ doesn't need it, see my post for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[CanVG.js](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) can render SVG elements onto the canvas element. Highstocks/Highcharts need it for all older (non-IE) browsers that implement canvas but not SVG rendering (i.e. Android <=2.3).

As the links posted by Thierry state, that file includes

> canvg renderer + rgbcolor.js + canvg.js (concatenated to one file)

Now this is important for you in case you develop a cross-device Highstocks/Highcharts application that **may ever be running offline:**
1. ensure `canvas-tools.js` from the modules directory is included in your project
2. add `global: {
            canvasToolsURL: '{local_path_to}/canvas-tools.js'
        }` to your highcharts options (as the default points to  code.highcharts.com)
3. in case your project uses an HTML5 manifest, make sure it's referenced there as well.

Hope this saves somebody the debugging confusion i went through and fully clarifies your question.